# Pandas filter, group-by and then transform

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe, which looks like the following:

```
  df =
      a          b
      a1.        1
      a2         0
      a1         0
      a3         1
      a2         1
      a1         1
```

I would like to first filter b on `1` and then, group by `a` and count number of times each group occurs (call this column `count`) and then attach this column with original df. `b` is guaranteed to be have at least one time `1` for each value of `a`.

Expected output:

```
  df =
      a          b.    count
      a1.        1      2
      a2         0.     1
      a1         0.     2
      a3         1      1
      a2         1.     1
      a1         1      2
```

I tried:

```
 df['count] = df.groupby('a').b.transform('size')
```

But, this counts zeros as well. I want to filter for `b == 1` first.

I also tried:

```
df['count'] = df[df['b' == 1].groupby('a').b.transform('size')
```

But, this introduces `nans` in the count column?

How can I do this in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with get the condition apply to `b` then `sum`

```
df['b'].eq(1).groupby(df['a']).transform('sum')
Out[103]: 
0    2.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```